# Always load temporary profile when login to windows 10.

Tags: windows-10

Jz upgraded my windows 8 to windows 10 and face this problem. My profile always reset to this temporary profile. I always have to create all my apps shortcut again on the desktop. Why is it my windows 10 always login using a temporary profile? Before this for windows 8 don't have this problem. I'm using my Hotmail account to log in.

Answer (score 0):

I found that making a local profile works and it restores the icons and shortcuts from windows 8 settings